Adding a Cooldown feature in Auto-Reply Script For Twitch
I saw this post on reddit (Auto-Reply Script on other Stream) and I find the solution of @puerdon very useful, but I wonder if it's possible to add a cooldown for the auto-reply in the script/html code (You can check the original html code in the reddit post above).
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://github.com/tmijs/tmi.js/releases/download/v1.8.5/tmi.min.js"></script>

    <script> 
        const client = new tmi.Client({
            options: { 
                debug: false,
                skipMembership: true, // 不接收 JOIN/PART 訊息
                skipUpdatingEmotesets: true,
            },
            connection: {
                reconnect: true,
                secure: true
            },
            identity: {
                username: 'your_twitch_username',            // [TODO]: input your Twitch username 
                password: 'genereated_oath_password'         // [TODO]: input the genereated oath password
                                                             // 1. go to https://twitchapps.com/tmi/
                                                             // 2. click "Connect"
                                                             // 3. You will get a password beginning with "oath..."
                                                             // 4. Copy the whole password and paste inside the 'genereated_oath_password'
            },
            channels: [ 'type_the_channel_you_want_to_listen_to' ] // [TODO]: input the channel name you want to listen to
        });

        let lastSchedule = undefined;
        function F(client, channel, message) {
            let currentMoment = new Date();
            function f() {
                client.say(channel, message);
            }
            if ((!lastSchedule) || (lastSchedule < new Date(lastSchedule - 120000))) {
                lastSchedule = currentMoment;
                f();
            } else {
                lastSchedule.setMinutes(lastSchedule.getMinutes() + 2);
                setTimeout(f, lastSchedule - currentMoment);
            }
        }
        client.connect().catch(console.error);

        client.on('message', (channel, tags, message, self) => {
         
            // this part is to skip the message sent by you,
            // or it will be prone to cause infinite loop
            if (self) {
                console.log(self);
                return;
            }

            // Here is the example of detecting a "hello" in a message
            // I first turn message to lower case and then check if the message includes "hello" in it
            // This can then detect "Hello", "hELLO", "HELLO" ... etc. variation of capitalization in the message
            if (message.toLowerCase().includes("hello")) {
                
                // if the condition above is met, then send "Hi" in the chat
                F(channel, client, "Hi!");
 
            }

        });


    </script>
</body>

</html>

Let's say, after sending the first "hello" by a chatter, I want to make the script to send the auto-reply "hi" once and will only reply again in the next 2 or 3 mins. In this way, it won't spam the same message if there's too many hellos in such a short period of time.
PS. I sent @puerdon a DM to help me with my request since I'm not a coder but he hasn't replied to me for a long while (maybe an abandoned account by now) so I thought of sharing it here if anyone knows how to add this feature.
Any helpful insights will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much!
Add some lines of code that will allow me to add a cooldown or buffer time between the automated messages.

If the auto-reply is the "hi" sent in response, this is how you can delay it:
            if (message.toLowerCase().includes("hello")) {
                
                // if the condition above is met, then send "hello" in the chat
                setTimeout(function() {client.say(channel, "Hi!")}, 1000 * 2 * 60);
            }

Or, if you want to make sure that a function, let's call it f cannot be executed twice in 2 minutes and postpone its call, then you can do something like this:


let lastSchedule = undefined;
function F(message) {
    let currentMoment = new Date();
    function f() {
        console.log(message);
    }
    if ((!lastSchedule) || (lastSchedule < new Date(lastSchedule - 120000))) {
        lastSchedule = currentMoment;
        f();
    } else {
        lastSchedule.setMinutes(lastSchedule.getMinutes() + 2);
        setTimeout(f, lastSchedule - currentMoment);
    }
}

F("a");F("b");F("c");F("d");



Adding the code to yours:
let lastSchedule = undefined;
function F(channel, client, message) {
    let currentMoment = new Date();
    function f() {
        client.say(channel, message);
    }
    if ((!lastSchedule) || (lastSchedule < new Date(lastSchedule - 120000))) {
        lastSchedule = currentMoment;
        f();
    } else {
        lastSchedule.setMinutes(lastSchedule.getMinutes() + 2);
        setTimeout(f, lastSchedule - currentMoment);
    }
}

you can define F just before
client.connect().catch(console.error);

for example.
You can call F by replacing:
client.say(channel, "Hi!");

with
F(channel, client, "Hi!");


Thank you for your reply! May I ask what are these values here in particular "1000 * 2 * 60"?
And your second answer is exactly what I wanted! I dont want the response "Hi" to be sent several times within 2 minutes to prevent spamming the same message. But where do I insert the code you provided. Im so sorry, Im not a coder, pardon on my noob questions.

@user26604864 1000 stands for the number of milliseconds in a second, 2 stands for the number of minutes we wanted and 60 stands for the number of seconds in a minute. In your case f would be a function that would consist of client.say(channel, "Hi!");, so you can replace the console.log(message); line with your client.say(channel, message); line.

Thank you for your clarification on the first part! Apart from the cooldown (your 2nd code), I love the addition of the delay (your first code). But I am really confused on how to put them together. If it is okay with you, can you show how they should be integrated together in the original code, just like you've shown in your first code?

@user26604864 added more details. Please let me know if there are any further questions.

@user26604864 I have edited your question and adjusted the code, I have put the function to a more appropriate place, adjusted tabulation of it and ensured that we call F instead of client.say so that the cooldown will apply. You will need to test this code to see whether it works, as it currently is only a code that looks good, but we need empirical results, i.e., test results.

Thank you for the updates you did! It was a bit clearer to me now. I just have a question: Where is the part for the delay and the cooldown? Can I also adjust the time in case I wanted to change it in the future?

@user26604864 it's all inside the F function. The if ((!lastSchedule) || (lastSchedule < new Date(lastSchedule - 120000))) checks whether we are either calling this function for the first time, or the cooldown period expired (120000 means 2 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds) and the lastSchedule.setMinutes(lastSchedule.getMinutes() + 2); increases the previous last schedule by 2 minutes (it's in the else branch, so we know we need to wait in this case). setTimeout(f, lastSchedule - currentMoment); schedules f to be executed at the time we need it.

I tried to test the updated code from the original post but it's not working unfortunately. However, when I tried using your first code only, the one for the delay, it works! I don't know why the code for cooldown is the one's not working.

@user26604864 it probably does not work due to some mistake you or I did. Do you see errors in the browser console while you test the other code?

Here's the screenshot of the browser console:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBk-HeHz532gnqnUNN6hJx7XoOw_Wu0Z/view?usp=sharing

@user26604864 the error tells us that client.say is not a function and it's right, because I passed the parameters in the wrong order.

@user26604864 I have changed function F(client, channel, message) { into function F(channel, client, message) { please change this line accordingly in your try.

I updated it and it finally works! No more error in the browser console. Thank you so much for your tremendous help. Appreciate it a lot!

@user26604864 happy to help!

Hi @Lajos Arpad ! Hope you're doing well. I just have a quick question, is it possible to detect a specific word from the Announcements instead of the chat messages in Twitch? Thanks in advance!

@user26604864 It is likely possible. If the announcement has a specific format or a specific subtext, then you can check for substrings or regular expressions. You can ask another question if you prefer and leave a link to it here in the comment section if needed. If you describe there how you are identifying that a message is an announcement, then I would hopefully be able to help you as well as other stackoverflow users.

That's very kind of you! Thank you for your help :D

@user26604864 please correct me if I'm wrong, my understanding is that you want to be able to detect whether a message is an announcement. Do you search for Attention | inside your string to make that distinction? You could as a separate stackoverflow question where you can elaborate on the code you have implemented in order to solve your issue and leave its link here. Of course, only if the problem is outside the bounds of short messages.

Im still using this same code. That's why I didnt create a new stackflow question. The issue I had with the code is that it does not detect the words inside the announcement, hence the question. I hope this clarifies it!

@user26604864 if you had a code that identifies any string that starts with Attention | as an announcement and nothing else, would that be feasible?

Yes, that is possible as long as the trigger word is "Attention | " for this instance

@user26604864 you can check it like this: !!(message.indexOf("Attention |") === -1) which checks whether the index of Attention | is -1, that is, not part of the string, in which case it's not an announcement, otherwise it's an announcement.

Where do I insert the line you sent in the code posted above? Im not sure where to put it in the script. Thank you for your understanding!

@user26604864 can you ask a separate question with the exact code that you already have? I would be more confident if you shared your latest version.

@user26604864 try replacing if (message.toLowerCase().includes("Attention")) { with if (!!(message.indexOf("Attention |") === -1)) {. Observations: I assumed that the inner block should be executed if it contains Attention |. If you want it to be negated, then you can just remove one ! from before the message. Your cose converts message to lower case and checks whether the lowercase text includes something that's not lower-case, which will never be true. includes is case-sensitive, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

I'll do the changes. What does -1 do in the code?

I tested the new changes and I noticed that it sends the message "get ready" even without the trigger message "attention" which is weird.

And unfortunately, it still doesn't detect words in the announcement after testing it many times. I dont know what the cause of it :(

@user26604864 so you want to send the "Get Ready" message when there was an announcement? I thought you want the opposite. Can you try if (!(message.indexOf("Attention |") === -1)) { instead? If it does not work, can you debug it by putting a debugger; line just before the if?

Oh there's a misunderstanding, sorry for the confusion! Let me give you another example of twitch announcement: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gj-FwyVzgDu_s16VXtZXtqOPaiGCGrIh/view?usp=sharing

The announcement says "Giveaway is starting!"
I wanted to use "giveaway" as the trigger word and it should send the word "congratulations"

My issue with the code is that it does NOT detect the word "giveaway" because it is part of the announcement.

The question is there a way to detect a specific word in the announcement?

Here's the latest version of the code for reference: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L5S7WuHWGiESEQKcqro-vFK8BPWNfgORRpdfM9cSj_Y/edit

@user26604864 sure there is a way. For starters try changing your message.toLowerCase().includes("Giveaway") into message.includes("Giveaway"). For example: https://jsfiddle.net/m04bqv58/

i'll try that solution.

Is it also possible to limit the search word in announcements only? It should not include the regular chat messages.

@user26604864 in order to do that you will need to be able to detemine whether a message is an announcement.

Ohh i seee, if it's not too much to ask, what do i need to add in the code to accomplish this?

@user26604864 I would be glad to tell you, but first, please tell me in plain words how exactly differentiate between the content of an announcement from the content of  non-announcement. If you could provide 3 examples of different announcements as well, that would be great. In my earlier comments I attempted to figure out this via questions, but at this point it seems to me that I need to see examples too in order to properly understand how they look alike.

Hii @Lajos !! Sorry for the late reply! been busy atm. About the code, I tried your suggestions but it still doesn't work unfortunately. I'm guessing the package used cannot detect words in the announcements.

@user26604864 it's a string and it should have the functions we use. There is an error in the code, but I'm confused about what your current code is, how it didn't work (did you get errors) and how you want to differentiate between announcements and non-announcements. I understand that you are busy, but when you find the time, please ask another question with details, such as your current code, possible inputs, expected behavior for them and explanation how the current try failed. And then please share the link to that question here.

Noted on that! I will post another question . Thank you again for your help!! :D

One concept that would implement a "cooldown" effect is called "debouncing."
Here's a simple debounce function:
function debounce(func, delay) {
  let timeoutId;

  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}

In your case, you'd encapsulate your functionality into a method like maybeSayHello() and pass that to this debounce function, along with your cooldown in milliseconds.

Thanks for your reply! but where do I insert the debounce function in the code?
Thank you for your understanding!
